Failure To Create a Playwright Testing (Preview) Workspace
I want to create a Azure Playwright Testing Workspace to start using it.
I've gone through the creation/deployment process, entered a Subscription/Resource Group/InstanceName etc.. and at the deployment phase it failed with a conflict status and this is the error message details:
The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (Code: ResourceDeploymentFailure, Target: /subscriptions/0d619252-d0e7-43b3-a190-a56243f79f0b/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.AzurePlaywrightService/accounts/PlaywrightInstanceName)
Any idea on what can cause this? Do I have to meet some prerequisities on my azure subscription?

They reply quite quickly here https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-testing-service

Thanks, I will check this out. It seams that there is another page to create workspaces (https://playwright.microsoft.com/create-workspace) instead of the Playwright section directly in the Azure portal.

This is a workaround: I've follow the same steps to create the Playwright workspace but this time I've selected another region (WestUs3 instead of EastUs) and the creation process succeeded.
I guess the EastUs have some issue at the moment that make the Playwright workspace creation unstable!?
